# Ember Data & Ember Fire Out of Sync Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I am walking through the tutorial of EmberJS and creating TodoMVC: http://www.thetechcofounder.com/getting-started-with-ember-js-using-ember-cli/

Instead of using the ember-cli-mirage from the tutorial, I'm wiring up Firebase and most of it works great. I am comfortable with Angular and Dart with Firebase, but am just starting to learn Ember.

I'm struggling with a checkbox input not updating Firebase and I'm not sure where to go from here.

In my component I have

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=todo.complete class="toggle"}}
```

My model looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    complete: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Using the Ember Inspector in Chrome I can see the ember data gets updated appropriately, but that change never makes it out to firebase. Is there something specific that needs to be done to wire up the Ember Checkbox helper with EmberFire?

[image: Ember Data vs Firebase]

### Update 1/21/2016

If I add a change handler to the ember component todo-item.js, I can send an action and got things to work as expected.

```
  change: function(e) {
    this.sendAction('updateTodo', this.get('todo'));
    return false;
  },
```

Not sure if this is the most appropriate way, but it moved me forward for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats the correct way.
Have a look at the Ember guides (they are awesome)

> Each record has a currentState property that explicitly tracks what
>   state a record is in at any given time. For instance, if a record is
>   newly created and has not yet been sent to the adapter to be saved, it
>   would be in the root.loaded.created.uncommitted state. If a record has
>   had local modifications made to it that are in the process of being
>   saved, the record would be in the root.loaded.updated.inFlight state.
>   (This state paths will be explained in more detail below.)

Initially you were only changing the current state.Have a more detailed look at the ember inspector. It shows current state as well as say canonical state.However I have not worked much with ember firebase adapter so can't comment on this more.

Happy Learning Ember. May the force be with you . :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kautilya, that's good to know. I was questioning it because when I had a different backend wired up, toggling the checkbox in that way also saved the result to the backend. Once I integrated emberfire that piece didn't happen automatically anymore.